# How can I constrain a generic type to implement a generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm working on a C# library for an API, simplified below:

```
// GET /foos
{
  "data": [
    { FooResource },
    { Fooresource },
    ...
  ]
}
// GET /bars
{
  "data": [
    { BarResource },
    { BarResource },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I want a user of my library to be able to specify what generic collection they want to use. So far, so good.

```
class ApiResources<T, TCollection> where TCollection : ICollection<T>
{
    public TCollection Data { get; set; }
}
```

However, I want this to specified when they instantiate the client singleton (in this case, `IFoo` and `IBar` are interfaces defining the various keys in the Foo and Bar resources)

```
class ApiClient<TFoo, TBar, TCollection>
  where TFoo : IFoo
  where TBar : IBar
  where TCollection : ???
{
    TCollection<TFoo> GetFoos()
    {
        ApiResources<TFoo, TCollection> resources = // make API call to get Foos
        return resources.Data;
    }

    TCollection<TBar> GetBars()
    {
        ApiResources<TBar, TCollection> resources = // make API call to get Bars
        return resources.Data;
    }
}
```

How do I go about doing this?
I'm getting `There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TCollection' to 'ICollection<TFoo>'`errors. I basically want to have `TCollection : ICollection<T>` without needing to define `T` in my `ApiClient` class definition.

edit:

I want to be able to write:

```
var client = new ApiClient<Foo, Bar, List>(); // List<T> for any T???
List<Foo> foos = client.GetFoos();
List<Bar> bars = client.GetBars();
```

Comment: I guess you need two type parameters for both collections. One `: ICollection<TFoo>` and one `: ICollection<TBar>`.

Comment: Is `Foo` and `Bar` related in any way other than `object`?

Comment: `Foo` and `Bar`aren't related. I thought of adding `TFooCollection` and `TBarCollection`, but it's kinda ugly so I was wondering if there were any other way. Note that in my real use case, I don't just have two type, but eight, so with individual collection types I would have 16 types in my `ApiClient` class definition.

Comment: How are you constructing the list? Is this through reflection? Then you can construct the concrete generic types in the client's constructor and pass them to resources. Of course, not as generic type parameters, but as plain method parameters of type `Type`.

Comment: I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResources<TFoo, TCollection>>(json)`

Comment: Your `TCollection` will have a type assigned, as soon, as you instantiate `ApiClient` (no matter how you do the constraint). So when you call `GetFoos` on that class, it will have the same type, as if you call `GetBars` (using both on the same instance). The definition of your `ApiResource` in combination with your usage of it inside `GetFoos` and `GetBars` leads to the conclusion, that `TCollection` got a generic parameter that fits both `TFoo` and `TBar`. So either you made a mistake there or I just understood your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no real way except adding type arguments for each collection. You could construct the `resources` type per reflection, but from then on you would lose all type safety and your methods would have to return `object` or `dynamic` because they don't know which type to cast to. You can't pass a pure `List` as a type parameter, because this type basically does not exist. There is `typeof(List<>)`, but it's just kind of a template for real types.

Comment: Hmm ok, I'll do that then. It makes for a very ugly initialization of `ApiClient`, but that shouldn't only be one line in any developer's implementation of my library I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `ApiClient` doesn't even use the `ApiResource`, so you can not constraint the `TCollection`-Type of your `ApiClient` to that of a `ApiResource` (which does not exist). So I would suggest you make the same constraint for `ApiClient`, that you made for `ApiResources`:

```
class ApiClient<TFoo, TBar, T, TCollection> [...] where TCollection : ICollection<T>
```

Usage:

```
var x = new ApiClient<Foo, Bar, SomeClass, Collection<SomeClass>>().GetFoos();
```

Or you make your [methods generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/twcad0zb.aspx), like this:

```
TCollection GetFoos<T, TCollection> where T : TFoo where TCollection : ICollection<T>()
{
    ApiResources<TFoo, TCollection> resources = // make API call to get Foos
    return resources.Data;
}
```

Usage:

```
var x = new ApiClient<Foo, Bar>().GetFoos<SomeClass, Collection<SomeClass>>();
```

But maybe I got your question entirely wrong. It is hard to determine what you want to achieve exaclty.

Comment: I've added what I want to be able to write to my question.